# How to get fields via children or childnodes

Tags: javascript

I need to get the children of the Section block. Namely fields and rabiobuttons. Next, check them for fullness. How to do it. I tried to get through `childNodes, children` but nothing worked.

In this case, I want to get the context of the section block and check the fields

**Such sections, I need to validate section by section and until the previous one is filled, I do not validate the next one.**

```js
const formStepTwo = document.getElementById("formStepTwo");
const Section = document.querySelectorAll(".Section");

formStepTwo.addEventListener("change", () => {
  //console.log( Section.item(0))

  let count = Array.from(Section).forEach((i) => {
    let context = i.children;
    context.item()
console.log( this.querySelectorAll(".input[type=radio]"))
      //console.log(context.forEach());

  });
});
```

```html
 <form class="stepTwo-profile" id="formStepTwo">
    <p class="stepTwo-profile-title">Демография</p>
            <div class="Section">
        <label for="age"
          >Возраст пациента<input
            type="number"
            class="stepTwo-profile-item-textAge"
            name="age"
            min="0"
            max="80"
            maxlength="2"
            id="age"
        /></label>
        <p class="stepTwo-profile-item-smTitle">Пол</p>
        <label for="male">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />Мужской
          <span class="stepTwo-profile-item-radionbtn"></span
        ></label>

        <label for="female">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />Женский
          <span class="stepTwo-profile-item-radionbtn"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You have to pass the index number in `item` function. `context.item(0)` will give you the first child node

Comment: @KanishkAnand Yes, but I cannot know the index as it is a pattern and may change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually check for input fields by targeting 'label' since they directly wrap over the `input` tag. Targeting through `.Section` can get a bit tricky, but is doable.

Another alternative is to directly target `input` fields using `querySelectorAll('input')` and then check for their type.

I've added example of both in the code snippet :

```js
const formStepTwo = document.getElementById("formStepTwo");
const labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");

formStepTwo.addEventListener("change", () => {
  let count = Array.from(labels).forEach((i) => {
    let children = i.children;
    Array.from(children).forEach((node) => {
      if(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
        switch(node.type) {
          case 'number' : validateNumberField(node);
             break;
          case 'radio' : validateRadio(node);
             break;
          // add more cases as required
          default: 
             console.log('add default');
        } 
      }
      
    });
  });
});

// Can also be done by targeting input directly 

const input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

formStepTwo.addEventListener("change", () => {
  Array.from(input).forEach((node) => {
      if(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
        switch(node.type) {
          case 'number' : validateNumberField(node);
             break;
          case 'radio' : validateRadio(node);
             break;
          // add more cases as required
          default: 
             console.log('add default');
        } 
      }
  });
});


function validateNumberField(node) {
  console.log('validating number field');
 // add your validation
}

function validateRadio(node) {
  console.log('validation radio button');
  // add your validation for radio
}
```

```html
<form class="stepTwo-profile" id="formStepTwo">
    <p class="stepTwo-profile-title">Демография</p>
            <div class="Section">
        <label for="age"
          >Возраст пациента<input
            type="number"
            class="stepTwo-profile-item-textAge"
            name="age"
            min="0"
            max="80"
            maxlength="2"
            id="age"
        /></label>
        <p class="stepTwo-profile-item-smTitle">Пол</p>
        <label for="male">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />Мужской
          <span class="stepTwo-profile-item-radionbtn"></span
        ></label>

        <label for="female">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />Женский
          <span class="stepTwo-profile-item-radionbtn"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Cool! When I finish filling this section, how do I send a signal to the next section of the same?

Comment: It should work across all sections automatically

Comment: but each section opening step by step, i cant validate all inputs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```js
const formStepTwo = document.getElementById("formStepTwo");
const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll(".Section")];

formStepTwo.addEventListener("input", () => {
 sections.forEach(s=>{
  const inps=[...s.querySelectorAll("input,select")].filter(el=>el.type!=="radio"||el.checked);
  console.log(inps.map(el=>el.name+":"+el.value))
 });   
});
```

```html
 <form class="stepTwo-profile" id="formStepTwo">
    <p class="stepTwo-profile-title">Демография</p>
    <div class="Section">
        <label for="age"
          >Возраст пациента<input
            type="number"
            class="stepTwo-profile-item-textAge"
            name="age"
            min="0"
            max="80"
            maxlength="2"
            id="age"
        /></label>
        <p class="stepTwo-profile-item-smTitle">Пол</p>
        <label for="male">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />Мужской
          <span class="stepTwo-profile-item-radionbtn"></span
        ></label>

        <label for="female">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />Женский
          <span class="stepTwo-profile-item-radionbtn"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
```

The script goes through all sections (currently there is only one ;-)) and collects all input values. (Radio buttons are only picked up if they are "checked".)

Comment: Ok.The fact is that such sections are opened gradually. I cannot validate all fields at once. I have to validate the first section (then it is closed) then I validate the next one after filling

Comment: There are many ways of stepping through a multi phase input process. One would be to only make the current section visible by setting it's CSS property `display` to `""` (default) and for all other sections to `"none"`. And then carry out the validation only for the visible section by using a suitable CSS selector.